# How can I find a class definition?

Tags: 8

I want to try override a class. I manage to replicate the description here;
https://www.hs2solutions.com/blog/drupal-how-override-core-drupal-8-service

However, I want to override the NodeViewBuilder class. How can I find out what definition to use?

Is there any documentation about how definitions works?

Comment: The definition in this context is the service providing that class, but I don't think this is what you want. What is NodeViewBuilder _not_ doing or you perceive it to not do that you need to do?

Comment: There is a bug in core that hardcode the language field formatter;
https://www.drupal.org/node/2637808
I want to add other formatter, but it is impossible as it is hardcoded.
So I want to override the class just to remove that bug until it is fixed in core instead of hacking the core files.
Any ideas?